# Links not appearing in ie 8 but they do appear in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have some regular garden variety links (this is asp.net MVC 2 so the routing might be a little weird) that appear in chrome but not ie 8.  How the heck does that happen?
[image: Here the link doesn't show up]

And here the Link does show up in chrome...
[image]

The links that I am refering to are the Add Patient and Add Encounter links on the bottom left hand corner of the page.
Here is the garden variety anchor tag that generates the link...

```
<a class="AddPatDlg" href="/PatientACO/AddPatient?PopID=1" title="Add Patient ACO Data">Add Patient</a>
<a class="AcoData" href="/PatientACO/AddEncounter?PopID=1" title="Add New Patient Encounter">Add Encounter</a>
```

Am I losing my mind?  How on earth is this possible?

*** I just noticed that if I scroll up to a place where I can't see the link and scroll back down the links will appear.  When I mouse over them, they will disappear... Help***

**update 2: more code**

```
<div id="countdownDiv" style="display:none" align="left">  
<p><font color="#990000"><b>This session has expired.  Please Refresh the page</b> </font></p>
<form action="/PatientACO/TemplateInfo?PopulationID=1&amp;ActiveAll=1" method="post"> <input type="submit" value="Refresh" id="test" /></form></div>
<div id="frReloadDiv" align="right">
  <form action="/PatientACO/TemplateInfo?PopulationID=1&amp;ActiveAll=0" method="post"> 

    <input type="submit" value="Show All" id="test1" /></form><form action="/PatientACO/TemplateInfo?PopulationID=1&amp;ActiveAll=1" method="post"> 

    <input type="submit" value="Active Only" id="Submit1" style="display:none"/></form>
</div>
<div id="tempplateInfo">
<div id="templateResult" class="scroll"></div>



<table id="table1" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>MRN</th>
    <th>Hospital Fin</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Date of birth</th>
    <th>Completed Pathway</th>
    <th>Completed Pathway Reason</th>
    <th>PCP Appointment</th>
    <th>Specialist Appointment</th>
    <th>Admit Date</th>
    <th>Discharge Date</th>
    <th>Discharge Disposition</th>
    <th>Discharge To</th>
    <th>Discharge Advocate Call</th>
    <th>Home Health Care Accepted</th>     
    <th>Safe Landing Accepted</th>
    <th>PCP Name</th>
    <th>PCP Phone</th>
    <th>PCP Appointment Location</th>
    <th>Specialist Name</th>
    <th>Specialist Phone</th>
    <th>Specialist Appointment Location</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Patient Room Phone</th>    
    <th>Phone</th>         
    <th>Payor</th>
    <th>MRN Type</th>       
    </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<a class="AddPatDlg" href="/PatientACO/AddPatient?PopID=1" title="Add Patient ACO  Data">Add Patient</a>
<a class="AcoData" href="/PatientACO/AddEncounter?PopID=1" title="Add New Patient  Encounter">Add Encounter</a>

    <p style="text-align:left">
    <b>

    </b>
    </p>     
 </div>
```

Maybe that table align left is throwing me for a loop. 
**UPDATE:  the align left doesn't appear to be doing anything... It seems as though "text-align:right" didn't fix anything**

I also noticed that in compatibility mode that issue doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Can you provide the complete HTML source code? Wild guess: Some style="float:something" are covering your links..

Comment: Its a good deal of code.  Alot of dealing with the Table that you see.  Are you sure you want to see all that?  Ill everything but the actual table data... That is just a nightmare.

Comment: Well - well for me this would be the only way to debug the code. Maybe someone else is psychic :D. Can you put it on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Or point us to the url hosted where we can debug for more assistance on the issue.

Comment: I could put it in js fiddle, but it would look pretty uggly still.  I guess I am trying to think through this program out lowed by spit balling ideas and what have you.  JSFiddle to follow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LdWBW/ <-There their be draggons.

Comment: You need to add your CSS as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying wrapping an element around your anchors:

```
<p class="action">
    <a class="AddPatDlg" href="#">Add Patient</a>
    <a class="AcoData" href="#">Add Encounter</a>
</p>
```

Then style the element accordingly:

```
.action {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```